# Setting a variable while using Jquery UI dialog box and accessing it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

This is what I am trying to achieve but it gives me 'undefined' and it is triggered before the dialog box open, what's wrong & where?

```
$(".shipment_refund").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var sel_option;
    var dialog = $('<p>Are you sure you want to refund this shipment? If yes then</p>').dialog({
            buttons: {
                    "With Shipment fee?": function() {sel_option = 1;},
                    "Without Shipment fee?":  function() {sel_option = 0;},
                    "Cancel":  function() {                            
                            dialog.dialog('close');
                    }
            }
    });
    alert(sel_option);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work hope so

```
$(".shipment_refund").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var sel_option;
        var dialog = $('<p>Are you sure you want to refund this shipment? If yes then</p>').dialog({
                buttons: {
                        "With Shipment fee?": function() {sel_option.val(1);},
                        "Without Shipment fee?":  function() {sel_option.val(0);},
                        "Cancel":  function() {                            
                                dialog.dialog('close');
                        }
                }
        });
        alert(sel_option);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/4s4r2aLu/2/) you can review too.

**EDIT**: adjust to add function and button to return users selected value from the dialog box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var choice;
    function doSomething (x) {
   if(x != null) {
       return x;
      }
    }
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ 
         autoOpen: false, 
              buttons: {
                        "With Shipment fee?": {
                            text: 'With Shipment fee?',
                                click: function() {
                                 choice = 1;
                                }
                        },
                        "Without Shipment fee?":  {
                            text: 'Without Shipment fee?',
                                click: function() {
                                 choice = 0;
                                }
                        },
                        "Cancel": {
                             text: 'Cancel',
                             click: function() {
                                   $("#dialog").dialog('close');
                                  }
                        }                           
                          
                        
                }
     });
    
    
  $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
     $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
        
         $("#storedValue").click(function(){
        var userChoice = doSomething(choice);
         if(userChoice != null){
             alert(userChoice);
              // clear choice
              choice = null;
            }else {
             alert("User did not chose a recordable answer.");
            }
         });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Refund">Are you sure you want to refund this shipment? If yes then (make selection and close dialog)</div>
<button id="storedValue">
Get Answer
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but like I said I need to set a variable while using Jquery UI dialog box and accessing it, alert works fine for me as well :)

Comment: See if the edit I made to my answer will better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how I achieved what I wanted to:

```
var sel_option;

$(".shipment_refund").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dialog = $('<p>Are you sure you want to refund this shipment? If yes then</p>').dialog({
        buttons: {
            "With Shipment fee?": function () {
                sel_option = 1;
                shipment_refund(e);
                dialog.dialog('close');
            },
            "Without Shipment fee?": function () {
                sel_option = 0;
                shipment_refund(e);
                dialog.dialog('close');
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                dialog.dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});
```